# javascript age calculator keep giving wrong numbers,

Tags: javascript

i am trying to do  a javascript program and calculate the age for the use, i have done the code below,

```
function submitForm() {
    var d = new Date();
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    var month = d.getMonth();
    var days = d.getDay();
    var minutes = d.getMinutes();
    var hours = d.getHours();
    var byear = document.dataform.year.selectedIndex;
    var bmonth = document.dataform.month.selectedIndex;
    var bday = document.dataform.day.selectedIndex;
    var bhours = bday * 24;
    var bmin = 60 * b hours;
    var dyears = year - byear;
    var dmonth = month - bmonth;
    var ddays = (days - bday);
    var dhours = hours - bhours;
    var dminutes = minutes - bmin;
    var daysTillBDay = 365 - bday;
    if (isLeapYear() == true) {
        dyears = year - byear;
        dmonth = month - bmonth;
        ddays = (days - bday) + 1;
        dhours = hours - bhours;
        dminutes = minutes - bmin;
        daysTillBDay = 365 - bday;
    }
    var el = document.getElementsByName('uyears');
    el[0].value = dyears + " years old.";
    el = document.getElementsByName('umonths');
    el[0].value = dmonth + " months old.";
    document.getElementsByName('udays')[0].value = ddays;
    document.getElementsByName('lmonths')[0].value = dmonth;
    document.getElementsByName('ldays')[0].value = ddays;
    document.getElementsByName('lhrs')[0].value = dhours;
    document.getElementsByName('lmin')[0].value = dminutes;
    document.getElementsByName('bdays')[0].value = daysTillBDay + " days left till your birthday.";
}
```

I think i will be work before  i try to run the program, after  i run the program, i found that the program give me almost everthing wrong, i have the year like 2013(newest yrs.), and the month i will equal the negativetive number such as  -1  if i enter 11. I just try to find users age, which i believe is  the date of today(today's gate)-(the birthday date), but is not workng now, anyobne know what>?

Comment: I suggest using `.value` rather than `.selectedindex` for your `<select>` elements. Also, consider using `getElementById` rather than the dot-syntax for element accession.

Comment: thank you! i am still trying now...

Comment: i have made a select list for the birthday month, date  and year select selection, so i think i should have select index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is very simple (and one mistake that I've made myself) - `new Date().getDay()` returns the day in the week (0 for Monday, through to 6 for Sunday), not the day in the month.

The function that you're looking for is `new Date().getDate()`, which returns 1 for January the 1st, 25 on Christmas Day, and so on.